# Sysbox-runc is not working as runtime for docker in Ubuntu

Tags: docker

I attempted to use sysbox-runc as the runtime for Docker on Ubuntu. sysbox-runc is operational. Nevertheless, an error occurred when I tried to create a container using Docker.

The command I was using: `docker run --runtime=sysbox-runc nginx`

docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:425: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:607: container init caused: process_linux.go:578: handleReqOp caused: rootfs_init_linux.go:366: failed to mkdirall /var/lib/sysbox/shiftfs/2e6d4302-28cd-4d9d-827e-6088b8b34e89/var/lib/kubelet: mkdir /var/lib/sysbox/shiftfs/2e6d4302-28cd-4d9d-827e-6088b8b34e89/var/lib/kubelet: value too large for defined data type caused: mkdir /var/lib/sysbox/shiftfs/2e6d4302-28cd-4d9d-827e-6088b8b34e89/var/lib/kubelet: value too large for defined data type: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled

Notes:

1. The same works fine with the default runtime runc.
2. Running docker and sysbox-runc as root.

Has anyone come across this before, please?

Answer (score 1):

Is it ubuntu 22.04 ? Do you use kernel 5.15.(>=48) ? plz take a look at

```
Unfortunately there isn't much we can do with Ubuntu kernels 5.15.(>=48) as they are apparently missing a Ubuntu-patch on overlayfs that breaks interaction with shiftfs.

If you can, please upgrade to newer kernels (e.g., 5.19, 6.0, etc.).

If you must use kernel 5.15, try using 5.15.47 or earlier.

If you must use kernel 5.15.(>=48), you can work-around the problem by either:

Removing the shiftfs module from the kernel (e.g., rmmod) or

Configuring Sysbox to not use shiftfs. You do this by configuring the systemd service unit for sysbox-mgr, and passing the --disable-shiftfs flag to Sysbox. See here for more.
```

https://github.com/nestybox/sysbox/issues/596#issuecomment-1291235140

Comment: Thanks, @sosogh. Yes, the kernel version is 5.15.0-58. Disabling shifts for sysbox-mgr has sorted the issue.